# creating WebAPI with other method names

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I know I have done this before, but when I create the default WebAPI from VS and tried to add a simple method like MySpecialMethod and then consume it from a client using httpClient, it errors with a 404 or id parameter is missing

I can call the Values/Get by doing something like this:

```
 GetAsync("api/Values").result
```

but it doesn't work if I do

```
 GetAsync("api/Values/MySpecialMethod").result
```

the two methods are identical for a simple test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure your WebApiConfig is configured with the `/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` entry. It sounds like you ony have `/api/{controller}/{id}`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the RouteAttribute to help clarify your methods routes.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Values/MySpecialMethod")]
    public string MySpecialMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

If you want to use this method, be sure to update your RouteConfig in AppStart to contain the following

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```